# How to use Having Clause and make it dynamic the value

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have 6 courses and I want to get those participant who finished the 6 courses.

| month | participant_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08 | 1 | 6 |
| 2021-08 | 2 | 6 |
| 2021-08 | 3 | 4 |
| 2021-08 | 4 | 6 |

Something like this

| month | participant_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08 | 1 | 6 |
| 2021-08 | 2 | 6 |
| 2021-08 | 4 | 6 |

Here's my sample query. I want to make it dynamic in the HAVING CLAUSE line. Instead of HAVING `count(c.name) >= 6`   --> I want to make it dynamic. The reason why I need to make it dynamic is once I need to delete 2 or more courses it will remain the count to those who finished the couses base on the number of courses.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CA.LOG_IN_DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM') AS MONTH, CA.PARTICIPANT_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT C.NAME)

FROM FRS.COURSE_ATTENDANCE CA

INNER JOIN FRS.COURSE_SCHEDULE_DETAIL AS CSD
ON CA.COURSE_SCHEDULE_DETAIL_ID  = CSD.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID
INNER JOIN FRS.COURSE_SCHEDULE AS CS
ON CSD.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID = CS.ID 
INNER JOIN FRS.COURSE AS C
ON CS.COURSE_ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN FRS.COURSE_CATEGORY AS CC
ON C.COURSE_CATEGORY_ID = CC.ID
INNER JOIN FRS.EMPLOYEE AS E
ON CA.PARTICIPANT_ID = E.ID
INNER JOIN FRS.MEMBER_ROLE AS MR
ON E.MEMBER_ROLE_ID = MR.ID

WHERE C.NAME IN (SELECT C.NAME FROM FRS.COURSE C
JOIN FRS.COURSE_CATEGORY CC
ON C.COURSE_CATEGORY_ID = CC.ID
WHERE CC.CATEGORY = 'RGB Standard')

AND CA.STATUS = 'P' 
AND C.MANDATORY = 'Yes' 
AND MR.ROLE_TYPE = 'RGB'
AND CC.CATEGORY = 'RGB Standard'

GROUP BY MONTH, PARTICIPANT_ID
HAVING COUNT(C.NAME) >= 6
```

Comment: Is `6` the number of rows in `COURSE`?

Comment: Yes it is. The Number 6 in the count is the courses who finished by the participant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace a hard-coded `6` with the actual total number of courses:

```
...
HAVING COUNT(C.NAME) >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FRS.COURSE)
```